# Laravel 4 Resource Controller shows single page no matter what typed in the url

Tags: php, routes, laravel, php-5.3, laravel-4

I have set up a resource controller using jefferyway's laravel4 generator as player.
So when i go to the url /players/show it shows me the show.blade.php. That's correct. But when I go to the /players/{whatever name field i can pass} it goes to the show.blade.php. No error thrown of httpnotfoundexception or anything.

These are the controller and routes file for the application.

http://paste.laravel.com/qwp 
http://paste.laravel.com/qwq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way it's supposed to work.
The `show` method on line 45 handles GET requests to `/players/{anything}`.

---

Jeffery Way has a really nice screencast series on Laravel 4, and he explains this in detail:

[**Resourceful Controllers**: Part 1](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/resourceful-controllers/)
[**Resourceful Controllers**: Part 2](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/resource-controllers-part-2/)

Comment: But how come if I do /players/create i get the create view page ? And also if I add login method to the controller , it also shows me the show.blade.php

Comment: @PranayaBehera - all GET requests to `/players/{any}` will be routed to `show`. The only two exceptions are `/players/create/` and `/players/{any}/edit`. Adding more methods to your controller won't change that, since a resourceful controller.

Comment: This routing thing is confusing me. Now I have disabled the show method. Now I can see those pages. But adding another method such as login, shows me NotFoundHttpException .

Comment: @PranayaBehera - Like I said, adding arbitrary methods to your resourceful controller won't help. You'll have to manually register it in your routes: `Route::get('players/login', 'PlayersController@login')`. Be sure to register this *before* your resource.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand the routing . :)

Answer (score 0):

When you register a resource controller, it will create those routes for you :

```
GET /players                                                    players.index            PlayerController@index                       
GET /players/create                                             players.create           PlayerController@create                      
POST /players                                                   players.store            PlayerController@store                       
GET /players/{players}                                          players.show             PlayerController@show                        
GET /players/{players}/edit                                     players.edit             PlayerController@edit                        
PUT /players/{players}                                          players.update           PlayerController@update                      
PATCH /players/{players}                                                                 PlayerController@update                      
DELETE /players/{players}                                       players.destroy          PlayerController@destroy
```

You can have this list with : php artisan routes

You can now see players.show will handle /players/*

Answer (score 0):

Use Example:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        // Has Auth Filter
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function()
    {
        // Has Auth Filter
    });
});
```